# Puppet Firewall - ctstate not available?

Tags: puppet, iptables

I got the task of converting some iptables rules into puppet firewall. I am currently stuck on this:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP -m comment --comment "drop new not syn"

I can't find a method to use neither --match or --ctstate in Puppet Firewall. How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like it wasn't available at all when you asked. Now it's available only in git repository (it means that you can't find it in module from Puppet Forge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git repository now contains the ctstate option.
You have to either use git version or wait for a new release on the puppet forge.

Hope this helps.